# Simplifying Repeated multiplication with for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a more elegant way to write this code?  I'm doing the same operation over and over again so it feels like there is but I can't think of it.

adults is a pandas dataframe.  weight is the persons sample weight and each ped variable represents a different disability type.

```
total_cognitive_m = (adults.weight * (adults.pedisrem==1)).sum()/1e6
total_mobility_m = (adults.weight * (adults.pedisout==1)).sum()/1e6
total_self_care_m = (adults.weight * (adults.pedisdrs==1)).sum()/1e6
total_physical_m = (adults.weight * (adults.pedisphy==1)).sum()/1e6 
total_vision_m = (adults.weight * (adults.pediseye==1)).sum()/1e6
total_hearing_m = (adults.weight* (adults.pedisear==1)).sum()/1e6
total_disabled_m = (adults.weight * adults.disabled).sum()/1e6
```

Comment: adults is a pandas Data Frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help a bit if you can make a function to reduce the repeated code:

```
def calc(adults, name):
    return (adults.weight * (getattr(adults,name)==1)).sum() / 1e6
```

but if you are using a number of separate variables, you will still have to have a separate assignment statement for each (excluding certain advanced but "hacky" solutions here):

```
total_cognitive_m = calc(adults, 'pedisrem')
total_mobility_m = calc(adults, 'pedisout')
... etc ...
```

Better if you can put the output data into some kind of collection, e.g. a dictionary.  In that case, you could do for example:

```
inputs_to_use = {
    'total_cognitive_m': 'pedisrem',
    'total_mobility_m': 'pedisout',
    ... etc ...
    }
```

You can then make your output dictionary using:

```
outputs = { key: calc(adults, name) 
            for key, name in inputs_to_use.items() }
```

and then look up values e.g. by doing

```
print(outputs["total_cognitive_m"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that the attributes are always there on the adults variable.

```
'''
The common behaviour of picking an attribute on adult 
like pedisrem and doing ( adult.weights * <attribute of adults> == 1).sum()/1e6
has been achieved using list comprehension, we store those attributes
in equalsToOne array and iterate over them.

'''

multiplier = 'weight'
equalsToOne = ['pedisrem', 'pedisout', 'pedisdrs', 'pedisphy', 'pediseye', 'pedisear']
total_cognitive_m, total_mobility_m, total_self_care_m, \
 total_physical_m, total_vision_m, total_hearing_m = 
[(getattr(adults, multiplier) * getattr(adults, var) == 1).sum()/1e6
 for var in equalsToOne]
total_disabled_m = (adults.weight * adults.disabled).sum()/1e6
```

Comment: Please explain your code rather than just having the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can define some collections to iterate your data, yo can use a **tuple** to declare each item propertie **adults.pedisrem,adults.pedisout,adults.pedisdrs , ...** and then use an array to storage each result as  this

```
properties = ("pedisrem","pedisout","pedisdrs")
totalValues = ("total_cognitive_m","total_mobility_m","total_self_care_m")
relationShip = {}
i = 0
for item in properties:
    relationShip[totalValues[i]]  = (adults.weight * (adults[item]==1)).sum()/1e6
    i = i + 1;

print(relationShip);
```